# Definition and Doubt: Universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-Algebras given by generators and relations

Tags: tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, projection-matrices, universal-property

Let $A:=\mathrm{C}^*(G,R)$ be the (defined) universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra generated by generators $G$ and relations $R$. As far as I can discern, there are two ways of defining such objects --- either using [category theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.4988.pdf) or [non-commutative polynomials and ideals](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Efreslon/Documents/M2/M2_Quantum_Groups.pdf).

The big ticket is that given any $\mathrm{C}^*$ algebra $A$ with $|G|$ generators that satisfy $R$ there is a unique surjective $*$-homomorphism $\mathrm{C}^*(G,R)\rightarrow A$. This is the *universal property*.

I have an informal way of thinking about universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras (that will shortly come into conflict with my second question).

My informal intuition for universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras is that we more or less form a large direct sum of all $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras that have $|G|$ generators which satisfy $R$ and that is where the universal property comes from (or sums of) projections $\bigoplus_\alpha A_\alpha\rightarrow A_\beta$.

---

**Question 1: How bad is this intuition? Is there something big that it misses (forget if it is formally incorrect)?**

---

That is more or less the question on definition. Now for my doubt. We can consider a particular universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $B$ which is generated by a *magic unitary* $u=(u_{ij})_{i,j=1}^4$. That $u$ is a magic unitary is to say that each entry is a projection $u_{ij}=u_{ij}^2=u_{ij}^*$ and that each row and column is a partition of unity:

$$\sum_{k=1}^4u_{ik}=1=\sum_{k}u_{kj}.$$

In the compact quantum group community ([say p.8](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Efreslon/Documents/M2/M2_Quantum_Groups.pdf)) this universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra is the setting for the algebra of continuous functions on the compact quantum group of permutations. The definition (of compact quantum group) requires a $*$-homomorphism $\Delta :B\rightarrow B\underset{\min}{\otimes} B$ and how this is constructed in this example is to define

$$\Delta(u_{ij})=\sum_{k=1}^4u_{ik}\otimes u_{kj},$$

and the way it is shown that this is a $*$-homomorphism is to show that the matrix:

$$\left[\Delta(u_{ij})\right]_{i,j=1}^4\in M_4(B\otimes B)$$

is a magic unitary, and so $\Delta:B\rightarrow B\otimes B$ is a *-homomorphism. Then the confusion comes in because in my informal intuition from a above $B$ is the largest object with magic unitaries... but here we have $B\otimes B$ which in my understanding is LARGER again than $B$ is also a sub-object of it...

**Question 2: Is there a way to resolve this confusion with my informal intuition of what a universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra (perhaps by arguing that the $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra generated by $\left[\Delta(u_{ij})\right]_{i,j=1}^4$ while living in a large space $B\otimes B$, is in fact smaller than $B$... or is my informal intuition messing up my understanding here?**

Comment: I believe your definition of universal property is slightly off. All that matters is that $A$ contains (not neccesarily distinct) elements $\{a_g \mid g \in G\}$ which satisfy the relations $R$. Then there is a unique (not necessarily surjective nor injective) $*$-homomorphism from $C^*(G,R)$ to $A$ taking $g \mapsto a_g$. Your map $\Delta$ is not necessarily injective nor surjective, just exists, and so whether not $B$ is "bigger" or "smaller" than $B \otimes B$ doesn't really come into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:  Your intuition is not only correct, but it also underlies the proof of the existence of the universal algebra.

Question 2: The universal property is only relevant in the domain.  All that is asked about the co-domain is that the relations be satisfied.

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer to Q.2... could you expand a little is it that we are only considering the algebra generated by the $\Delta(u_{ij})$... it feels a little self-referential to me at the moment.

Comment: The universal property says that whenever you have elements in some C*-algebra $A$ satisfying your relations (they need not be generators) you get your map.

Comment: Along the same lines as my comment above, even if the universal property required the co-domain to be generated by the $\Delta(u_{i,j})$, one could easily get around by replacing the codomain with the algebra generated by these elements.